# How to Change Timestamp in DDMMMYYYY HH:mm:ss:ssssss format to yyyy-MM-dd format in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sql-timestamp

I have a timestamp in the below format. How to get date in yyyy-MM-dd format from it?

```
+-------------------------+
|15APR2021:03:53:54.458387|
|15APR2021:03:53:53.830339|
|15APR2021:03:53:54.297856|
+-------------------------+
```

I have tried using the below but is getting null.

```
scala> spark.sql("select to_date('15APR2021:03:53:54.297856')").show()
+------------------------------------+
|to_date('15APR2021:03:53:54.297856')|
+------------------------------------+
|                                null|
+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you. If time is 24Hr format then change hh to HH.

```
spark.sql("select to_date('15APR2021:03:53:54.458387', 'ddMMMyyyy:hh:mm:ss')").show()
```

Comment: Seems to fail on newer versions of spark without a legacy flag (which I didn't try) `SparkUpgradeException: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0`...

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use the proper date mask which it seems to be:

```
ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
```

Here is an example assuming timestamp is in a column called ts

```
df.withColumn("date", to_date($"ts", "ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")).show(false)

+-------------------------+----------+
|ts                       |date      |
+-------------------------+----------+
|15APR2021:03:53:54.458387|2021-04-15|
|15APR2021:03:53:53.830339|2021-04-15|
|15APR2021:03:53:54.297856|2021-04-15|
+-------------------------+----------+
```

Or using syntax from your example:

```
spark.sql("select to_date('15APR2021:03:53:54.458387', 'ddMMMyyyy:hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS')").show()

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|to_date('15APR2021:03:53:54.458387', 'ddMMMyyyy:hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS')|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                       2021-04-15|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks for the help. However, it is still giving me null. I am using spark version 2.3. May be that is why it is not working for me.